# Visual Basic:TRY\CATCH exception handling issues

Tags: vb.net, exception, try-catch

I am working on an employee database and am having issues with my TRY\CATCH for saving records as it pertains to exception handling. The issue I am experiencing is that it will run the TRY and ignore the CATCH, allowing invalid data to pass and save to the file. I am very new to visual basic and am unsure of why this is not working. Here is my code for the form:

```
Option Strict Off
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmEmployeeData
'Variable Declarations
Dim BlnisChanged As Boolean = False
Dim empFirstName As String
Dim empMiddleName As String
Dim empLastName As String
Dim empNumber As Integer
Dim empDepartment As String
Dim empTelephone As String
Dim empExtension As Integer
Dim empEmailAddress As String
Dim empSelection As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim intTryParse As Integer = 0



Private Sub frmEmployeeData_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Adds the department options to the combo box dropdown list
    ComboBoxEmpDepartment.Items.Add("Accounting")
    ComboBoxEmpDepartment.Items.Add("Administration")
    ComboBoxEmpDepartment.Items.Add("Marketing")
    ComboBoxEmpDepartment.Items.Add("MIS")
    ComboBoxEmpDepartment.Items.Add("Sales")
End Sub

Sub ClearItems()
    'Clears text boxes
    txtFirstName.Clear()
    txtMiddleName.Clear()
    txtLastName.Clear()
    txtEmployeeNumber.Clear()
    ComboBoxEmpDepartment.ResetText()
    txtTelephone.Clear()
    txtExtension.Clear()
    txtEmailAddress.Clear()
End Sub

Sub SaveItems()
    Dim savedEmployeeFile As StreamWriter

    Try
        'Creates the employee file
        savedEmployeeFile = File.CreateText(fileName)

        'writes information entered by user into file
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtFirstName.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtMiddleName.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtLastName.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtEmployeeNumber.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(ComboBoxEmpDepartment.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtTelephone.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtExtension.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtEmailAddress.Text)

        'Closes the file
        savedEmployeeFile.Close()

        BlnisChanged = False

        'Clears the text boxes
        ClearItems()

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Throws error if file could Not be created
        MessageBox.Show("Unable To Create File. Please Try Again", "Error In Saving")

    End Try
End Sub
Sub AppendToFile()
    Dim savedEmployeeFile As StreamWriter

    Try
        'append to file
        savedEmployeeFile = File.AppendText(fileName)

        'writes information entered by user into file
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtFirstName.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtMiddleName.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtLastName.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtEmployeeNumber.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(ComboBoxEmpDepartment.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtTelephone.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtExtension.Text)
        savedEmployeeFile.WriteLine(txtEmailAddress.Text)

        MessageBox.Show("Employee saved successfully.", "Success")

        'Closes the file
        savedEmployeeFile.Close()


        BlnisChanged = False

        'Clears the text boxes
        ClearItems()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("No file exists. Please select 'Save As' Option.", "Error In Saving")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveRecord.Click
    Dim savedEmployeeFile As StreamWriter

    'EXCEPTION HANDLING
    'verifies first name field content
    If txtFirstName.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("First name cannot be blank", "Invalid Entry")
    End If
    'verifies middle name field content
    If txtMiddleName.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Middle name cannot be blank", "Invalid Entry")
    End If
    'verifies last name field content
    If txtLastName.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Last name cannot be blank", "Invalid Entry")
    End If
    'verifies employee number field content
    If txtEmployeeNumber.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Employee number cannot be blank", "Invalid Entry")
    ElseIf Not (Integer.TryParse(txtEmployeeNumber.Text, intTryParse)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Employee number must be numeric", "Invalid Entry")
    ElseIf CStr(txtEmployeeNumber.Text) < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Employee number must be positive", "Invalid Entry")
    End If
    'verifies department field content
    If ComboBoxEmpDepartment.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Employee department cannot be blank", "Invalid Entry")
    End If
    'verifies telephone number field content
    If txtTelephone.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Telephone number cannot be blank", "Invalid Entry")
    ElseIf Not (Integer.TryParse(txtEmployeeNumber.Text, intTryParse)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Telephone number must be numeric", "Invalid Entry")
    End If
    'verifies extension field content
    If txtExtension.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Extension cannot be blank", "Invalid Entry")
    ElseIf Not (Integer.TryParse(txtExtension.Text, intTryParse)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Extension must be numeric", "Invalid Entry")
    ElseIf CInt(txtExtension.Text) < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Extension must be positive", "Invalid Entry")
    End If
    'verifies email address field content
    If txtEmailAddress.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Email Address cannot be blank", "Invalid Entry")
    End If


    'If no filename exists, will prompt save dialog box and prompt user to save as
    If fileName = String.Empty Then
        If sfdSave.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            fileName = sfdSave.FileName
            SaveItems()
        End If

        'If filename exists, append item to file
    Else
        AppendToFile()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    'Clears all content currently within text boxes
    txtFirstName.Clear()
    txtMiddleName.Clear()
    txtLastName.Clear()
    txtEmployeeNumber.Clear()
    ComboBoxEmpDepartment.ResetText()
    txtTelephone.Clear()
    txtExtension.Clear()
    txtEmailAddress.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    'Closes Program
    frmUserSelection.Show()
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles sfdSave.FileOk

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    'Picture Obtained From:
    '"User Add Icon-Shine Set: Add New User, Add User." Free Icons PNG. Accessed 14 October 2018. https://www.freeiconspng.com/img/2487
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Turn Option Strict back on. That's the very first thing you should do. Then fix any compiler errors you see as a result.

Comment: Rather than a text file you write out by hand, research *serialization*

Answer (score 0):

A `Catch` block only executes if an exception is thrown from within the `Try` block.  I don't see anything here which would cause that to happen.  It appears as though you're misunderstanding this a bit.

Don't put *validation* logic in a `Catch` block.  All that should go there is code to handle an *exception* if one occurs.  For example, if the connection to a database fails because the database itself is offline, or if writing to a file fails because the file can't be found/opened.

Put your *validation* logic before you even make the attempt to save it.  If the user input fails validation, don't attempt to save it.  Instead, return an error to the user.  Only if your custom validation *passes* would you then begin the `Try`, write to your data store, and handle an exception if one occurs.

Comment: Thank you, David. I guess I'm uncertain as to where I would put this in my code for validation when a user is entering the information.

Comment: @user7217915: Whenever you want to check the user input.  For example, if you have a button the user clicks to save their data, the first thing that click handler should do is validate that input.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I added it to the btnSave section and it is validating now, but still saving rather than forcing them to enter the information (I will re-update my code

Comment: @user7217915: Looks like you're notifying the user of the validation error, but not preventing the save from happening anyway.  Consider maintaining a `Boolean` value in your function.  Something like `isValid`.  Initially set it to `True`, but in any of your validation checks set it to `False`.  After all of the checks, if it value is `False` then at least one of them failed.  Only perform the save if that value is `True`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this! I did that and it is now working like a charm :) I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help, as I've been plugging away at this for hours to no avail.

Comment: would there be a way to validate each field realtime as it is entered and the user tabs to the next field? When I save, it displays multiple popup boxes. Just curious if or how I could do that.

Comment: @user7217915 There is support for real-time validation.  Which library are you using for your forms?